# How to enter the DOB using Selenium/Python?

Tags: python, selenium, date, xpath, css-selectors

I am not able to enter & select the DD-MM-YY.

**Here the html code...**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="date" class="form-control input_design" name="dob" id="dob"                placeholder="DOB" required>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML the *`<input>`* is having the type attribute set as ***date***

```
<input type="date" class="form-control input_design" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="DOB" required>
```

The [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) elements of *`type="date"`* create input fields that let the user enter a date, either with a textbox that validates the input or a special date picker interface. As an example:

```
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-07-22"  min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">
```

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* of ***type="date"*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.input_design#dob[name='dob']").send_keys("04-04-2022")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control input_design' and @id='dob'][@name='dob']").send_keys("04-04-2022")
  ```